# Sending an envelope: getting 301 response code back

Tags: php, docusignapi

PHP 7.4, Windows Server 2012, IIS8

I'm using the DocuSign PHP SDK method createEnvelope, which sends the envelope object to their server. The URL is

```
https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2.1/accounts/cheese-burger/envelopes
```

with these headers

```
X-DocuSign-SDK: PHP
Authorization: Bearer ee-i-ee-i-oh
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
```

I'm successfully using the JWT key for, say, getUserInfo, but when I submit the envelope I get

```
HTTP/1.0 301 Moved Permanently
```

back. As far as I can tell, the envelope is created correctly, I know the JWT key works, and account id is correct. Any insight as to why I'm getting a 301 redirect?

Comment: 301's usually have a 'Location' header; where is it trying to redirect you?

Comment: Great question. That's what I get for working too late into the evening: didn't even think of it. The url was missing the protocol, and I was correcting it in the wrong spot. So...that's working now. Thanks!

Comment: Awesome, glad to help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@matt clark supplied the answer in the comments--the 301 response header helped the OP realize that he was missing the protocol section of the URL.